# Why do some interfaces not display unless I'm in config mode?

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos, gns3

I'm using a Juniper vSRX image in GNS3.

Here is my output before entering into config mode:
[image]

And after entering into config mode:
[image]

Why can I see my `ge0/0/0` in config mode, but not outside of?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely emulating using the wrong NICs. If the correct NICs are used the ge interfaces should appear in 'show interfaces terse'.

Configuring them is one thing... but having them actually present within the virtualized device is entirely different.

If you're using virtualbox to run the vSRX image then try - paravirtualized network (virtio-net) NIC. I believe that should help.

Comment: I am using `paravirtualized network (virtio-net)`. What's weird is that they will appear fine, and then when I connect two vsrx routers together in GNS3, the interfaces appear to disappear.

Comment: I've come across this with GNS3 before when running IOS-XRv and GNS3 decides to overwrite my chosen interfaces. You may have stumbled across a GNS3 bug hard to say without seeing you're actual setup.

I'd suggest looking at the GNS3 forums if you haven't already. Also make sure you're running the latest version of GNS3 and VirtualBox.

Comment: I've started another question based on additional troubleshooting tonight - http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20276/could-launching-a-virtual-router-with-less-than-recommened-ram-cause-interfaces