# Could launching a virtual router with less-than-recommened RAM cause interfaces to not initialize?

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx, gns3

I'm trying to launch a few vSRX devices through GNS3 (and VirtualBox). The issue that I'm running into (*I think*) is that my interfaces seem to not properly initialize if I don't start the instances with at least 1024 MB of RAM.

I'm working on a lightweight laptop, and was hoping to run a few instances at 512 MB or somewhere along those lines. From the troubleshooting I've done over the past couple nights though, it seems as though you can in fact launch the instances with less than the recommended RAM, but it doesn't necessarily mean everything is going to be initialized properly.

Specifically, if I launch with 1024 MB of RAM, I can do:

- `root@vsrx-a> show interfaces ge0/0/0 terse`

.. and have my interface displayed properly. However, launching with a lower amount of RAM doesn't show any physical interfaces (in this case, `ge*`).

Are my assumptions here accurate, or could there be something else going on that I'm now aware of?

Comment: How lightweight is the laptop, what make/model?

Comment: It's a macbook air -- 4GB ram

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe officially vSRX needs 4 GB RAM, 2 CPU and a min of 16 GB disk space. If this requirement is not met, an instance can behave abnormally and will be hard to debug. Maybe you are facing a display-only issue, but with packet processing and some feature enabled, surely you will be struggling with control and data plane memory.